# How can I do this?

Tags: python, string

```
l = [u'Dav watson', u'Davis']
```

Result should be:

```
[
    {
        first_name: 'Dav',
        last_name: 'Watson'
    }, {
        firstname:'Davis'
    }
]
```

Comment: Have you attempted to solve this on your own yet?

Comment: You should atleast attempt to write a good title.

Answer (score 5):

```
import string
l = [u'Dav watson', u'Davis']

[dict(zip(('first_name', 'last_name'), map(string.capitalize, l[0].split()))),
 {'firstname': l[1]}]

# returns:

[{'first_name': u'Dav', 'last_name': u'Watson'}, {'firstname': u'Davis'}]
```